# Related list not visible to a profile

Tags: related-list

I have page layout on order object. And there I have a related list of a object. This is access able to admin, but I have a different profile who have access to this page layout but not able to see the related list. What may be the reason for this. Please guide me to get the solution.

Comment: Does the profile have access to the order object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that profile does not have **read access** to the object in question, then the related list will not appear for a user with that profile. The behavior is similar to having a field on the page layout, but setting the field level security to not visible.

Comment: In addition to this: check the deployment status of the child-object. If this is not set to 'Deployed' it will not be visible to certain profiles (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B3KyIAK)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Robin's answer, the Field Level Security setting for the lookup field must be set to Visible for the Profile in question.