# Certain Profiles Unable to View Related List on Custom Object

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, related-list

Related List is shown for admin and not for other profile, even this profile has access in child object read, and in the fls too. can someone help me to figure it out please.

Comment: Did you look at the Page Layout Assignment in the parent object and which page is assigned to that parent record(in case you have Record type for that parent object, first check the record type of that record)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72004/related-list-not-visible-to-a-profile?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This occurs, if the other profiles do not have at least read access to the related list Object.
For example, if it is a Related Opportunities, ensure that the profiles have read access to Opportunity.

Comment: they all have acces to all objects

Comment: Have you checked the page layout assignments of the object?

Comment: yes its just one PL is one is assigned to all profiles